# What is RECEIVE_SECURITY_SMS permission?

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

I am running ManifestExplorer ([Download Link](http://www.isecpartners.com/storage/tools/mobile-security/ManifestExplorer.zip)) tool in my Android Device. It returns the list of permission required by installed applications. One of the application installed requires

> "android.permission.RECEIVE_SECURITY_SMS"

I have tried google but cannot find significance of this permission.

Can anyone help me with the same.

Comment: This could be a permission defined by an OEM/ or even the app developer them selves. Can you tell us what the application is ?